# Mongoose indexing by score

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, indexing, mongoose

I'm trying to create a leaderboard in mongoose and am having issues indexing my score schema by ascending score.

here is my code:

```
db.once('open', function callback () {
 console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
 var scoresSchema = new Schema ({
  score: Number,
  user: String
 }, {autoIndex: false});

 scoresSchema.index({ user: 1, score: -1 });

 StatScore = mongoose.model('Score', scoresSchema);
});
```

And it's output is as follows

```
[ { _id: 57715497860521f404cfebf0, score: 87, user: 'seth', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 577157151f39c2320548e6e5, score: 99, user: 'seth', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 57716a4613e701890608d18a, score: 97, user: 'seth', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 57716a7413e701890608d18b, score: 135, user: 'john', __v: 0 } ]
```

Any ideas on why it is not sorting properly? I've been looking at other working and examples and can't see where im going wrong.

Comment: sorting and indexing are not the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449570/mongoose-default-sorting-order

Comment: @BrianGlaz i understand that but i'd like to index my data so that every time a new entry is saved it will save it in descending score order so that i will always have the first 10 scores of my database as the top 10 scores.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not completely clear and could be useful if you put your query on your question. But here you have some clues that can help you.

- You must be aware that you are creating a compound index. This means that the index will be ordered taking the **user** as first argument, then the **score**.
- Be sure you are calling the **sort** method. It is common to think that the index will maintain our collection ordered on disk. This is not true. You can think on an index as a table of references to the documents on a collection that is ordered according what you have set on the index configuration. So, despite you have configured your index to be sorted by **score**, it does not mean that the collection will be ordered in disk, and when you do a query getting all the content, it will be displayed in the order the data was found in the collection that is not necessary the order you want.

Hope this helps to you.

Also, you can read this documentation about sorting and indexing on mongo that I've found useful: [mongo sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#examples), [mongo indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/).